# Can I select the parent of an element based on an active class of the child?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have modified an accordion to fit my page as a fixed contact form, when you click the accordion tab the form slides to the right. This all works fine. The tab though, is a little large for the page and I want to make it smaller, kind of reflecting a file tab. I have figured out how to re-size the tab itself but what I need to do is take away the background color of the parent, because it sits right below the tab.

[Here is a fiddle to show what I mean](http://jsfiddle.net/immediateahughes/5vLL88ux/7/)

The purple portion of the tab is color I want to keep, the black is what I want to take away. The problem I'm facing is that when I take away the black colour of the tab, it also takes away the colour of the content when its opened.

There is one distinguishing class in the accordion that I think can help, when you open the tab and then close it, a class (class="collapse") is generated and added to the anchor tag like so:

```
<div class="contact">
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                     <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" class="collapsed">
                      Contact Us
                    </a>
                  </h4>

                </div>
                <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <!--form goes here-->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

With the background colour I want to remove being on the `<div class="panel panel-default"></div>` is there a way I can remove it with the added class on the anchor tag which is a child of it?

[image: From this]

to this:

[image: to this:]

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/parent/

Comment: If u want the black part be the same size as the purple one, just add "width: 135px;" to ".panel.panel-default" styles. See it in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5vLL88ux/15/)

Comment: In this case, u can remove the style for ".panel.panel-default".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to go for anything else or don't need to make it too much complex. Just change the CSS as below:

```
.panel.panel-default {
 background-color: transparent;   
 }
 .panel-default .panel-body {
 background:#000;
 }
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5vLL88ux/14/)**.

If you wish to fill the panel-title with color on expand, use jquery.

```
$('#myCollapsible').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
// do something… add css background etc.
});

$('#myCollapsible').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
// do something… remove css background or set to transparent etc.
});
```